# Drawbacks of "Self Defined" Special Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to implement a `Vector class` which has some self defined arithmetic methods , but also makes use of some  [Builtin Arithmetic Special Methods in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).

In this  [video@7.30 (12k likes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ohzBxoFHAY&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc&index=5),a Builtin Special Method's definition is changed ("**add**(self,other)") with a self defined one.

Are there any drawbacks to this method or in fact, any benefits like combining builtin and selfdefined method definitions?

Comment: Please repeat [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `__add__` exists so that it can be overriden, if this is what you are referring to.

Comment: @chepner Overwriting Builtin methods and User defined ones is not the same. I am referring to the "unseen repercussions" of redefining builtin methods,  like you suggested in your answer.

Comment: @Starzar The question would be improved if you had included the code you were asking about, rather than simply posting a link to a video tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely why the special methods exist, so that you have something you can override to implement certain operations.

For *all* types (even the built-in ones), `x + y` is implemented with `x.__add__(y)`. Providing a definition for `__add__` is how you make your own classes work with the operators provided by the language.

The only real drawback is that you might not have *a* definition. There might be two or more ways to "add" values, and neither one is more important than the other. In that case, you'll probably want to leave `__add__` undefined and provide explicit methods instead.

For example, there are two common ways to multiply two vectors: using the dot product and using the cross product. You *could* use `__mul__` to implement the dot product, and provide an explicit `cross` method for the cross product. Or you could use `__mul__` for the cross product and define `dot` for the dot product.

Or, you can define both `dot` and `cross`, leaving `__mul__` undefined. That way, there won't be any silent surprises when `x * y` doesn't give you the result you expected: it will simply fail. You can also provide a definition that intentionally fails, with information about *why* `*` isn't supported.

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    raise TypeError("multiplication not supported. Use 'dot' or 'cross' method instead.")
```

Comment: ... or use `@` for dot, `__mul__` for element-wise, and have a separate method for cross. :)

Comment: Maybe? `@` was a pretty arbitrary choice to begin with. It was chosen because it was one of the few ASCII symbols still available, not because it carries any strong association with multiplication. I hesitate recommending it be used for much of anything.

Comment: I mentioned it because that's what numpy uses, more or less